# JAVA split sentence by words, punctuation and quotes

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to split sentence using regular expression.

Sentence:

```
"Hallo, I'm a dog. The end. Someone said: \"Earth is Earth\". Is it good? I like it! 'He is right' said I."
```

Current regular expression:

```
\\s+|(?<=[\\p{Punct}&&[^']])|(?=[\\p{Punct}&&[^']])
```

Current result:

```
{"Hallo", ",", "I'm", "a", "dog", ".", "The", "end", ".", "Someone",
"said", ":", **""**, """ , "Earth", "is", "Earth", """, ".", "Is", "it",
"good", "?", "I", "like", "it", "!", **"'He"**, "is", **"right'"**,
"said", "I", "."}
```

I have extra `""` before first quote sign and it doesn't split the ' from words.

Result which I want:

```
{"Hallo", ",", "I'm", "a", "dog", ".", "The", "end", ".", "Someone",
"said", ":", """ , "Earth", "is", "Earth", """, ".", "Is", "it",
"good", "?", "I", "like", "it", "!", "'" , "He", "is", "right", "'",
"said", "I", "."}
```

Edit:
Sorry! More code then:

```
String toTest =  "Hallo, I'm a dog. The end. Someone said: \"Earth is Earth\". Is it good? I like it! 'He is right' said I.";
String [] words = toTest.split("\\s+|(?<=[\\p{Punct}&&[^']])|(?=[\\p{Punct}&&[^']])");
```

and it produce words list:

words = {"Hallo", ",", "I'm", "a", "dog", ".", "The", "end", ".", "Someone",
    "said", ":", **""**, """ , "Earth", "is", "Earth", """, ".", "Is", "it",
    "good", "?", "I", "like", "it", "!", **"'He"**, "is", **"right'"**,
    "said", "I", "."}

Comment: I don't see any Java code in your question.

Comment: @LutzHorn The regular expression is a Java code.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Why not Perl, Python, or Ruby?

Comment: @LutzHorn It could be. But what of it? If the OP marked it as Java, and he has a valid problem which *is* in the language, it makes sense for him to ask for help that could, potentially, involve non-regex code, in Java.

Comment: @canimbenim - How do you want to solve the single quote issue? You don't want word's like *it's* to split, but what about a single quote that denotes possesion like *dolphins' noses*?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, Right... I haven't thought about it :/ I will need to  think about it, as even if I do my own parser I am not sure if I can write something which will always work because there is no chance to write a simple code which will work for i.e.: 'It is suspicious' and dolphins' noses :/ I would need to have knowledge about what type of word it is - noun or verb or adjective or other... Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try that :

```
\\s+|(?<=[\\p{Punct}&&[^']])(?!\\s)|(?=[\\p{Punct}&&[^']])(?<!\\s)|(?<=[\\s\\p{Punct}]['])(?!\\s)|(?=['][\\s\\p{Punct}])(?<!\\s)
```

The problem with `said: \"Earth` was that you were splitting before and after the space, so I have added a negative look-ahead and a negative look-behind to the parts splitting around punctuation.

I also have added two cases for splitting the single quotes if they are preceded or followed by a space or some punctuation.

But, as @RealSkeptic wrote in his comment, this will not take care of

> a single quote that denotes possesion like dolphins' noses

And you may need to write a real parser for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and separate your special characters from your words:

```
yoursentence.replaceAll("([^\\w ])", " $1 ").split(" +");
```

This messes up spaces, but i guess you don't need to care about how many are in your sentence next to each other. Also, a "bit" simpler than yours :D

copyable code to try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Hallo, I'm a dog. The end. Someone said: \"Earth is Earth\". Is it good? I like it! 'He is right' said I.";
    String replaceAll = s.replaceAll("([^\\w ])", " $1 ");
    List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(replaceAll.split(" +"));

    for (String string : asList) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it might be possible to solve the problem with a single regexp, my approach is to split the work into several steps where each does one thing.

So I suggest you create an interface:

```
public interface IProcess {
    List<String> process (List<String> input);
}
```

Now you can start with a list that contains the whole sentence as the first element and which returns words split by white space:

```
    return Arrays.asList (input.get (0).split ("\\s+") );
```

The next step is to write processors for each kind of special characters and chain them. For example, you can strip `.,!?` at the end of each word to clean the input for the next steps.

This way, you can easily write unit tests for each processor whenever you find a bug and easily narrow down the part of the chain which needs to be improved.